# How does homebrew prevent being used with sudo?

Tags: homebrew, sudo

When I try to install using `homebrew` with `sudo` privileges, for example `sudo brew install lua`, I get this message

> Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
>   As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
>   build scripts full access to your system.

I understand this error and think that it is a good idea, but how does `brew` detect that I'm using `sudo`? Is this feature something that I can implement in my applications as well?

Comment: This question may also belong on one of the Stack Exchange sites that deals with Unix or Unix-like OS's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brew.sh uses `id -u` to verify if it runs as root. If it runs as root, it will return 0. See this [line](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh#L241). After that, it's just a question of showing a message in accordance to the id obtained.

Comment: Wow that's a lot more simple than I thought it would be.

Comment: @EliSadoff Depending on the language you're programming in, there is most probably a solution to know the software runs as which user.

Comment: I write a lot of things in ruby, so I can just use ``check = `id -u` `` and go from there.

Comment: @EliSadoff great! If this satisfy your needs, make sure to select it as an answer!

Comment: I will. I'm just waiting one more minute so I'm allowed to.